# Can we write a custom method to load data from S3 bucket into Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario where I need to load Json data from s3 bucket in to Spark DataFrame, But problem here is my data in S3 bucket is encrypted with Javax.crypto library using AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding encryption algorithm. when I tried to read data from S3, spark is throwing error that this is not json data since it is in encrypted formate. Is there any way I can write my custom spark code which reads data from s3 bucket as file input stream and apply this decryption process using Javax.crypto util to convert and assign it DataFram? (I want my spark custom code to run over the distributed cluster). Appreciate your help.

Comment: if file is small, can be loaded into memory and decrypted, and then DataFrame created from string.

Comment: Im having 500GB data for every day, and Im seeing 1000s of files

Comment: you can write a custom dataframereader

Comment: could you please provide me some steps

Comment: @Jeevan Did you solve it?